# Telerik RadGrid Returns Empty Grid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

As the title suggests I am having a hard time getting my RadGrid to properly display records. Here is my code:

### ASP.NET CODE

```
<Telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="pnlMain">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMain" LoadingPanelID="MasterPanel" />
        <Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgShowData" LoadingPanelID="MasterPanel" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</Telerik:AjaxSetting>
<Telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rgShowData">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgShowData" LoadingPanelID="MasterPanel" />
        <Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMain" LoadingPanelID="MasterPanel" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</Telerik:AjaxSetting>

[ ... ]

<div class="FormContent" style="height: 1500px">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server">
        <div class="box">
            <Telerik:RadGrid ID="rgShowData" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" Width="600px" Height="400px"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Visible="false" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" TableLayout="Fixed" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="quote_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="quote_date"
                            ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="QuoteDate" DataFormatString="{MM/dd/yy}" />
                        <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="intl_amt" HeaderText="Global" SortExpression="intl_amt"
                            ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="IntlAmt" DataFormatString="{0:N}" />
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </Telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

### VB.NET CODE-BEHIND

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    [..Validation Code..]
    rgShowData.Visible = True
    rgShowData.Rebind() ''Automatically calls NeedDataSource
End Sub

Private Sub rgShowData_NeedDataSource()
    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = GetPostData(dateValue1, dateValue2)
    rgShowData.DataSource = ds.Tables("radGrid")
End Sub

Private Function GetPostData(ByVal dateValue1, ByVal dateValue2) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable("radGrid")
    Try
        dt = data.GetInfo(dateValue1, dateValue2)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Return ds
End Function
```

I am calling RadGrid's Rebind() property instead of DataBind() and as I walk through the code in debugger mode I can see that the datasets and datatables are being populated with the correct data. Everything works as it is supposed to until I get to the webpage and the RadGrid is empty. I don't receive any error messages, so I am not sure what could be the cause of this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my RadGrid was not being populated, despite the Data Source containing the correct data, was because the RadGrid and Data Source had different formats that I was unaware of and could not be converted.

I am not exactly sure how it happened, as I modeled this RadGrid after many others I have created, but my RadGrid would not accept the strings returned by the Data Source. I had to take what was in the Data Source, convert the values to decimals in the correct format, and then place them in another data table to be sent to the RadGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have **AjaxControlID** with **btnSubmit**. It is basically saying that btnSubmit will initiate AJAX requests and update rgShowData.

```
<Telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnSubmit">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlMain" LoadingPanelID="MasterPanel" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</Telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Comment: I added btnSubmit to the AjaxManager and it did not return the desired outcome.

Answer (score -1):

using radgrid inside **asp:panel** is not the best way. Better use the **RadAjaxManager**.

Dont affraid to use **RadAjaxManager**, its easy to use. Just add the **RadAjaxManager** in your page. And click on **Open Configuration**, there you need to click on **One Control**(radgrid,button) and map it to **other one**  (just a Checkbox tick)

try it out and let me know if you face any difficulty.
Here's the documentation of **RadAjaxManager**

[see this documentation about RadAjaxManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxmanager.html)